# Creating a new dataframe column by comparing strings of two unequal dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

What is the most efficient approach in Python to create a new data frame column `df1['Description']` obtained when `df1['a']` string is equal `df2['b']` string? When condition is met, then a separate string `df2['Description']` would be assigned to `df1['Description']`. `df1` and `df2` are large data frames (~1/2 Million rows) of unequal sizes.

`df1`:

```
a    b
Z0   1  
Z1   2
A7   3
```

`df2`:

```
b    Description
W2   asadsde  
Z0   evrverve
A7   eveveerv
```

I would like:

```
df1
a    b   Description
Z0   1   evrverve  
Z1   2   jsbdbcje
A7   3   eveveerv
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Z0', 1],['Z1', 2], ['A7', 3]], columns=['a', 'b'])
    
    a  b
0  Z0  1
1  Z1  2
2  A7  3
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['W2', 'asadsde'], ['Z0', 'evrverve'], ['A7', 'eveveerv'], ['Z1', 'jsbdbcje']], columns=['a', 'Description'])
    
    a Description
0  W2     asadsde
1  Z0    evrverve
2  A7    eveveerv
3  Z1    jsbdbcje
    
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='a', )
    
    a  b Description
0  Z0  1    evrverve
1  Z1  2    jsbdbcje
2  A7  3    eveveerv
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering these are your dataframes:

```
df1
a    b
Z0   1  
Z1   2
A7   3

df2
b   Description
W2  asadsde
Z0  evrverve
A7  eveveerv
Z1  jsbdbcje
```

Code to achieve your desired output using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign):

```
df1.assign(description = df1['a'].map(dict(df2.values)))


    a   b   description
0   Z0  1   evrverve
1   Z1  2   jsbdbcje
2   A7  3   eveveerv
```

In df1 if you want only matched rows then use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna):

```
df1.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Z0', 1],['Z1', 2], ['A7', 3]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['W2', 'asadsde'], ['Z0', 'evrverve'], ['A7', 'eveveerv'], ['Z1', 'jsbdbcje']], columns=['b', 'Description'])
```

After the initialization you can join your dataframes based on your `a`column and setting your other datafrmae's `b` column as index . So the code will be-

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('b'),on='a')
```

And your desire output will be -

```
    a   b   description
    0   Z0  1   evrverve
    1   Z1  2   jsbdbcje
    2   A7  3   eveveerv
```